# Call 2 functions from one call PHP

Tags: php, function

How can I call two functions from a single call in PHP?

```
function 1() {
  // do stuff
}

function 2() {
  // do other stuff
}
```

Then I want to call those 2 functions from a single call

```
(calling_functions_1_and_2($string));
```

How do I go about doing this?

Elaborated:

This function strips a string of any URL's

```
function cleaner($url) {
  $U = explode(' ',$url);

  $W =array();
  foreach ($U as $k => $u) {
if (stristr($u,'http') || (count(explode('.',$u)) > 1)) {
  unset($U[$k]);
  return cleaner( implode(' ',$U));
}
}
  return implode(' ',$U);
}
```

This function strips a string of any special characters, etc.

```
function clean($string) {
   return $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

The string that these functions perform on is in a JSON array.

So calling one of the functions

```
clean($searchResult['snippet']['title']); // wanting to remove all special characters from this string but not URL's.
```

**But on this string below I do want to remove special characters and URLs, so how would I call both functions the most efficient and easiest way?**

```
cleaner($searchResult['snippet']['description']);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to do this because on some strings I want to call both functions but on other strings I only want to call 1 or the other function. Each function performs different things.

Comment: `function test() { function1(); function2(); } test();` ?

Comment: @castis is it really that simple?

Comment: @Mike Please add an example with input and expected output. To see what exactly you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a function that calls both is a nice and simple way to do it:

```php
function clean_both($string)
{
    return clean( cleaner( $string ) );
}
```

This way you just do the following to clean it both ways:

```php
$clean_variable = clean_both( 'here is some text to be cleaned both ways' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a second parameter to one of the functions, let's take clean()

```
function clean($string,$urlRemove = false) {
       if ($urlRemove) {
          $string = cleaner($string);
       }
       return $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
    }

function cleaner($url) {
  $U = explode(' ',$url);

  $W =array();
  foreach ($U as $k => $u) {
if (stristr($u,'http') || (count(explode('.',$u)) > 1)) {
  unset($U[$k]);
  return cleaner( implode(' ',$U));
}
}
  return implode(' ',$U);
}
```

Having it like this, function clean() will default to only strip the url (when called like `clean($string);`), but if you call it like

```
clean($string,true);
```

you will have both functions beeing executed on the string.